# Update some elements of a symbolic matrix

Tags: matrix, mathematical-optimization, symbolic, indexed-variable

I am trying to build, update and manipulate a binary matrix in an optimization problem using `NMinimize`.

The variable to be optimized on is a vector `xs` of positive integers of variable length $n$ (number of columns in the matrix), where each element indexes the row of the matrix where a value 1 is defined.

I never succeeded to define a binary/boolean or even integer domain for `xs` in `NMinimize` (it seems to produce only real values), so I ended up trying to round the vector elements at the last moment.

The problem is that the matrix is a symbolic expression, so even if I tried to use `Indexed` to delay the evaluation of `Round`,I still don't know how to update the matrix elements without triggering a `Set::write: Tag Indexed in Indexed[{{0,0,0},{0,0,0}},{1,1}] is Protected.`

```
makeX[m_:2,xs_:{1,1,2}]:= 
Module[{n,matrix},
n = Length[xs];
matrix = ConstantArray[0,{m,n}];
Do[ Indexed[matrix,{ Round[Indexed[xs,i]],i}]=1, {i,n}];
matrix
];
makeX[] // MatrixForm
makeX[2,{1.66718,1.65312,1.07973}]//MatrixForm
```